# From variable name to type hint

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there a way to define a type hint via the variable name?

Example:

Everytime I name a variable `response` in my code, I want it to have a type hint to `django.http.HttpResponse`.

My use case is type hinting for IDEs like PyCharm. Up to now I have no use case to evaluate this at run-time.

I would like to have general (as opposed to pycharm specific) solution.

I want to avoid doing manual and explicit type hinting over and over again.

Please tell me why you down-vote this question. I am curious and willing to learn.

Comment: @MooingRawr I read the link you provided before posting. I don't see how this can help me. I don't want to do explicit type hinting again and again.

Comment: I don't think that linking variable name to a type inexplicitly is a good practice. Just whenever you define it use a comment to define it's type to make it explicit rather than having it defined somewhere outside of a visible code

Comment: @Alex I try to avoid obsolete comments. What is the meaning of this comment? It tells me that this thing called "response" is ... surprise, suprise ... it tells me that this is a RESPONSE. Yes, great news! I like the guidelines of the author of "clean code" and "clean coder": http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1326509

Comment: @guetti thing is not everyone who will work with your code will use pycharm, if fact the right way to fix it is to add typing to django source code, so whenever you call any HttpResponse returning function pycharm will know about it and will help you to work with it. So you might help everyone by contributing to django.

Comment: With [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) you can explicitly specify the type of the variable every time. Though, this requires the 3.6 Python version.

Comment: @m0nhawk thank you for pointing me to PEP 526. Python 3.6 is no problem in this context. Yes, up to now the type needs to specified every time again and again :-(

Comment: @Alex ... yes you are right. If every method which returns a response has the matching type annotation, then I don't need the magic I ask for in this question. Nice hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Add type annotations to all methods which return a HttpResponse

A variable in Python needs to declaration. It gets created by being a [lvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) (my definition, maybe there is a better way to describe this)

```
response=handle_request(request)
```

If `handle_request()` has a type annotation, then there is no need to do type annotation for `response`.

This does not answer the question directly, but solves the problem behind the question.

This answer is based on the comment of user Alex. Thank you :-)

Comment: This is my preferred answer, but I need to wait until tomorrow to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

## Add type hints via auto-generated stub files

You can auto-generate create [stub files](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) (with .pyi extension) which contain type hints for the source code.

I guess this auto-generating is not difficult to implement.

This has the benefit to the answer called "Add type annotation to all first usages of response", that the source code does not contain the same line (`response: django.http.HttpRequest`) several times

Drawback: you need a build-step to create the stub files.

Comment: small hint: if you have a versatile test suite (or other ways of running usecases automated), you can benefit from generating typings at runtime via [MonkeyType](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType) or [pyannotate](https://github.com/dropbox/pyannotate).

Comment: @hoefling great. This is fun, this made me laugh. Crazy idea, but great news. Create type annotations by executing the tests. Thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

## Add type annotation to all first usages of `response`

```
def test_foo():
    response: django.http.HttpRequest
    response=handle_request(request)
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

This has the drawback that `response: django.http.HttpRequest` needs to be put before each first usage in a scope. AFAIK there is no way to define this only once per module level